# Cycling BBDB matches and suppressing popups in gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus, bbdb

I'm trying to get BBDB playing nicely with gnus. There are two related features I can't get to work, though:

(1) Stopping junk windows popping up.

(2) Cycling through different matches with TAB, rather than using the popup or any sort of new buffer.

As far as I can see, `bbdb-mua-pop-up` and `bbdb-complete-mail-allow-cycling` ought to control these, respectively. Can't get them to work, though. Instead, pressing TAB currently does the following:

(1) If there's a single matched entry with a couple of different email addresses, creates a *BBDB* window, which I don't want. Cycling works as expected here.

(2) If there's not a single entry matched, pops up the usual emacs *Completions* buffer in one of the other windows, which I don't want, either. You can't cycle between the matches here with TAB.

Relevant bits of .gnus:

```
(bbdb-initialize 'gnus 'message 'mail)
(bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'gnus 'message 'mail)

(setq bbdb-complete-mail-allow-cycling t
      bbdb-mua-pop-up nil)
```

The window layout is more or less the three-pane one described at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusWindowLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the question 1 is:

`(setq bbdb-completion-display-record nil)`

As to the second question 2 do not have an answer. bbdb3 configuration seems to be somethings like a state secret.